# Visual studio - c# with Razor - First step

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I wanted to know what files I need to add to a blank .NET c# Razor project to load my first page up.

I have created a view called Index.cshtml and inside it contains:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index"; 
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
```

I have created a controller called HomeController.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace My_Website.Models
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Default1/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

When I run this application, I get the following error:

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

Is there a way to redirect the script to point to Index.cshtml straight within the View folder without having to put in a Home directory to satisfy the default layout?

Comment: Where did you create your view? The error message tells you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: In the Views folder. Without having to create a new Home folder... Is there a way to redirect the script to point to Index.cshtml without having to put in a Home directory?

Comment: @JamesT You should save your view as 'Views\Home\Index.cshtml'. That's how the controller knows where to find for it.

Comment: @JamesT I agree with the rest of answers and comments. I would like only add that it's a nice way to do that is first CreateController => Right click on action name (in your example Index) and choose from menu CreateView - Visual Studio will create proper file and directory for you.

Comment: @JamesT: Don't do that.  What will you do when you create another controller?

Comment: This question is not about "C# with Razor" page. What you are using here is ASP.NET MVC framework. This is why you have models, controllers and views. The problem you have here is caused by routing in ASP.NET MVC. The Razor is just an engine for creating HTML Views (with C# code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the view file path in your action method:

```
return View("~/Views/Index.cshtml");
```

Answer (score 4):

Your view **must** be in the Views folder, then either a sub folder for the corresponding Controller **or** a folder called Shared underneath Views. Try either:

`Views -> Shared -> Index.cshtml` **not a good idea**

`Views -> Home -> Index.cshtml`

Comment: This is the right answer to the original question... thanks. but my new question is answered by Ufuk..

Comment: @JamesT Ah no problems glad I could help anyway :)